# Codeigniter do not select the data whose date is less than 2019 which have some types from joined table

Tags: php, codeigniter, eloquent, codeigniter-3, eloquent-relationship

I'm working on Codeigniter rest API project and came across a problem.
I would like my model not to select the data whose registration date is less than 01/01/2019 and whose types in the joined table equal type_1 type_2, but if the registration date is less than 2019 and the type in the joined table equals type_3, type_4 the request must return the record .

so i tried this method how can i get this result?

```
code: // MyModel

function get_data() {
    
    
    $id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';

    if ($id != null) {
        $this->db->where('ID',$id);
        $result =  $this->db->select('POST.ID,POST.DATE,'
        . ' TYPE.Post_Type P_TYPE,)
        ->join('TYPE', 'POST.TYPE_ID = TYPE.ID', 'left')
        ->order_by('POST.ID', 'DESC')
        ->where_in('POST.Post_Type  = type_1, type_2')
        ->where('POST.DATE<', "to_date('01/01/19', 'DD/MM/RR')", FALSE)
        ->get('POST');
    } 
    return $result;
}
```

So i want that its not returning data with type_1 type_2 which are <than 2019, but can get others type

Comment: post your `CREATE Table....` schema of tables `TYPE` and `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why did you filter in where post.date less than if you want greater than that date?.
Second, where_in does accept values as an array on the second parameter.
well here is my code, I reorganize your code to a much readable one. If you are trying to query date in timestamp or date field it should be in format of Y-m-d

> 

```
function get_data() {
    
    
    $id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';
    
    $types = array('type_1', 'type_2');
    if ($id != null) {
        $this->db->where('ID',$id);
        $this->db->select('POST.ID, POST.DATE, TYPE.Post_Type as P_TYPE,', FALSE);
        $this->db->join('TYPE', 'POST.TYPE_ID = TYPE.ID', 'left');
        $this->db->order_by('POST.ID', 'DESC');
        $this->db->where_in('POST.Post_Type', $types);
        $this->db->where('POST.DATE >', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('01-01-2019')) );
        $this->db->from('POST');

        $result = $this->db->get();
    } 
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hello first of all Thank you for your support, this request no longer sends me the upper records <2019 whith type_1 & type_2, I just don't want to display the lower lines> 2019 with type equal type_1 & type_2

Comment: but its must bring me back lines> lower than 2019 which have another type & lines < 2019  with all TYPE

Comment: so you want is to get data of (type 1 and type 2 that is greater than 01-01-2019) and (type 3 and type 4 data regardless of dates)?

Comment: Let's say i want is to get data of (type 1 and type 2 that is lower than 01-01-2019) and( type 1, type 2, type 3 and type 4 data that is greater than 01-01-2019)

Comment: in this case I would just use a raw query and just union 2 queries for example 

$query= ' SELECT x* FROM ( 
select fields from POST where POST.Post_Type IN ("type3", "type4") AND POST.DATE > '2019-01-01'

UNION ALL

select fields from POST where POST.Post_Type IN ("type1", "type2") 
 )x ' );

$return  = $this->db->query($query);


since you want to get data of (3 and 4 that is greater than 01-01-2019) then use it as first query then use another query for 1 and 2 without date because you still want to get data that is lower and greater than 01-01-2019

Comment: Can you please show me in my eloquent example, i appreciate your support

Comment: The eloquent way would be to query to separate then just use array_merge($result1, $result2) to merge 2 array result

`code`
$query1 = $this->db->get()->result_array();
//second query here...
$query1 = $this->db->get()->result_array();
//then...
$result = array_merge($query1,$query2);

Comment: i accept this answer, it's work in other cases i found solution for my case its to define two function in my model and call them by using my api controller with using if else if and else method thank you for help